# Ignore MyPy “is not valid as a type” error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, mypy

I'm maintaining a Python 3.3 library. I've updated MyPy, and now I'm getting the [“is not valid as a type”](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases) error.

The offending code is in the `enum` package, which I've vendored. In `mypi.ini`, I ignore all errors from that package, but the errors technically occur where I'm using `Enum` as a superclass in my own code.

Is there some way to reassure MyPy that `Enum` really is a type? I'd rather not add ignores all over my code.

Example:

```py
from .vendor.python.enum import Enum

class ExampleEnum(Enum):
    Hello = 1
```

MyPy produces the following error:

```
st3/sublime_lib/footest.py:3: error: Variable "sublime_lib.vendor.python.enum.Enum" is not valid as a type
st3/sublime_lib/footest.py:3: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

Comment: Does explicitly importing Enum or one of its subclasses help?  That plus maybe a type hint?

Comment: I've added an explicit example to the question. It directly imports `Enum`, but MyPy does not recognize it as a type.

Comment: You can try to use ``if TYPE_CHECKING`` to define ``Enum`` as a type. Not sure whether that will work with Python 3.3 (!!!) though.

Comment: I, too, would like to suppress this error.  In my case, I'm using generated proto files for gRPC and don't want to go through the hassle of using, yet another, plugin to generate files for type hinting.  The generated DESCRIPTORS in the `generated_file_pb2.py` files aren't accepted by mypi.

Comment: fyi I had the same issue with grpc / generated files, I solved it by excluding the directory with the generated files (mypy.ini with `exclude = pb2_files`). Also mypy==0.942 + grpc-stubs==1.24.6 got rid of most errors, upgrading mypy to the latest version produces a ton of errors